# Error using Gradle android.support.v7.widget.CardView dependency in my project (IIntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: android

When I'm in the process of creating a project in IDEA IIntelliJ I'm getting this error

> Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not download artifact 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0-rc1:cardview-v7.jar'
>   Artifact 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0-rc1:cardview-v7.jar' not
>   found.

this is what i'm doing

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use CardView or RecyclerView I think that you need something like this in your build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android 
{
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    [...]
}
dependencies 
{
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
}
```

Comment: Don't use "+", use the latest version number instead. Then when someone tries to build your app in the future (under Android 10) they will know which libraries you depended on.